# Get orientation of the android phone screen

Tags: android, screen, orientation

Is there some differences between getRequestedOrientation and getResources().getConfiguration() to get the orientation of the android phone screen ??

Answer (score 0):

if you are in activity then use

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

else if not in activity then use your activity instance by passing it,

```
 your_activity_instance.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Another way:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(myCurrentActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==  
 Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
 {
 // code to do for Portrait Mode
 } else {
// code to do for Landscape Mode         
 }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.